# OpalRB: Using functions as parameters

Tags: javascript, ruby, opalrb

I'm using Opal in my MeteorJS project.

I'm trying to figure out a way to do the `Meteor.startup` code, but it doesn't seem to work..

I thought this would work:

```
require 'native'

@Meteor = `Meteor`
@Meteor.startup do
  puts 'Go'
end
```

But it doesn't. The compiled code should be like the following:

```
Meteor.startup( function() {
  console.log( "GO" );
} );
```

It's very regular to throw functions as parameters in JS, how would we do this in Opal?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/marcandre/meteor-opal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work fine:

```
require 'native'

@Meteor = Native(`Meteor`)
@Meteor.startup -> {
  puts 'Go'
}
```

*Note that using Native you pass a lambda instead of a block*

Answer (score 1):

You can either use Native (which underneath wraps JS objects), as suggested by Elia or...

```rb
@Meteor = `Meteor`
@Meteor.JS.startup do
  puts 'Go'
end
```

Calls like `X.JS.y` compile directly to `X.y()`. Similarly, you can access properties like `X.JS[:propname]` (compiled to `X.propname`)